# Проверка на наличие ошибок  stmt. Надо ли?

Tags: mysqli, php

Есть стандартный код подготовленного запроса mysqli:

```
   $stmt = $this->_db->stmt_init();
   $stmt->prepare('INSERT INTO mysqli_test(title,content,year) VALUES(?,?,?)');
   $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $title, $content, $year);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
```

Нужно ли отлавливать ошибки в этом куске, а если нужно, то каким оптимальным способом. То что видел, по моему ужасно. Пример:

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
 if(($stmt->prepare(«SELECT title FROM sk2_articles WHERE id > ? and id < ?»)      ===FALSE)
 or ($stmt->bind_param('ii', $id_min, $id_max) === FALSE)
 or ($stmt->execute() === FALSE)
 or ($stmt->bind_result($title) === FALSE)
 or ($stmt->store_result() === FALSE)
 or ($stmt->fetch() === FALSE)
 or ($stmt->close() === FALSE)
 ) {
 die('Select Error (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);
 }
```

Цепочка обязанностей же выглядит довольно громоздкой.

П.С. Где можно глянуть куски кода реальных проектов, чтоб ориентироваться на код профессионалов.

Comment: Exceptions. Очень удобный механизм. Масса полезностей и преимуществ. А отлавливать ошибки или нет - это дело хозяйское

Comment: Потому и городят фреймворки, чтобы, по возможности, освободить прикладных программистов от подобной нудной работы :)

Answer (score 1):

Второй код очень кривой.

Большая часть этих проверок не несет смысла сама по себе (поскольку функции, которые не работают с базой, никак не связаны и с `$stmt->error`, а выдают обычные warnings), а от остальных можно отказаться, если научить mysqli транслировать ошибки базы в исключения РНР. Это делается одной строчкой,

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

которая пишется *перед* коннектом.
После этого отовсюду выпиливается весь код, который проверяет результат любых функций mysqli - от коннекта до выполнения запроса - mysqliвсегда сообщит обо всех ошибках сама.